# Enable location detection in TestRigor

Tags: testrigor

could you please explain how I can enable location detection in the TestRigor browser? For user it looks like browser pop-up, but rigor skip this pop-up and I receive only errors which caused by unavailable location (important for my project). I mean this pop-up

[image: example of pop-up]

Comment: This is not yet a released feature

Answer (score 0):

testRigor automatically accepts location popups and other browser-based permission requests. There is no need to add an action in your custom steps to handle them.

Update: testRigor has updated this to allow you to click on these browser pop-ups. You can click these by using OCR only if you have screenshots enabled at the OS level.

To do this, you can check it in `Settings->Advanced`, then scroll down to Desktop Web Fine Tuning and select `Use OS (more features)` from the `How to take screenshots:` dropdown.

Once that is done, you can use a command to click on the browser pop-up. For the one in the picture, you can say the following:

```
click "Allow" using OCR only using the mouse
```